# Create model during runtime

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

is there a way to create a model during runtime? I've created a little GUI overlay plugin with a button
and some other elements.
If the button is pressed i want to create some cylinders in the scene that are connected by joints at specified positions with specified dimensions.
The position and size of the cylinders are not known during startup of Gazebo, so i don't want to use
SDF files as used in most tutorials.

I've tried to find tutorials or a way to create models during runtime, but couldn't find anything. Is there
a way to solve my problem?

Maybe i could create a string, that looks like a SDF file, as in this tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gui_overlay&cat=user_input
But i hope there is a better way, because the creation of such a string that simulates a SDF file with a couple of calculated parameters, that need to be used, would be complex and not very convenient.
Maybe there are some already existing methods of gazebo, like (pseudocode):
"createCylinder(position, radius, length);
addJoint(cylinder, jointType);
...."

Thank you very much,
skmCry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12376/create-model-during-runtime/) by [skm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2267/skm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-01-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-02-15**:
I'm actually interested in doing this as well... I think if we start looking at the model editor code we will find the examples we want.
the path from the root of gazebo is `gazebo/gui/model/`

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-02-15**:
I'm actually interested in doing this as well... I think if we start looking at the model editor code we will find the examples we want.
the path from the root of gazebo is `gazebo/gui/model/`

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-02-15**:
The model editor uses SDF as well, see this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/411807a3a83074ef00bea1482a62d81775003e28/gazebo/gui/model/ModelCreator.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#ModelCreator.cc-1435

You don't necessarily have to handle a string. You can have an `sdf::ElementPtr` and manipulate its attributes with the SDF API: http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/sdformat/api/dev/classsdf_1_1Element.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can see an example of a very very similiar plugin [here](https://github.com/PeterMitrano/gzmaze). It generates/reads mazes in gazebo

[example video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmyzxpGMjcg)
[example video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Li4-KSfIrsc)

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexandreB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2369/alexandreb/) on 2016-03-15**:
Nice thanks alot! Will be looking a this!

**Comment by [skm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2267/skm/) on 2016-03-19**:
I'm sorry for the late response, although i've created this topic, but i was very busy and couldn't continue working on my project.
Anyway, thanks a lot Peter, your code helped me a lot to get an idea how gazebo works and a real-time creation of models can be accomplished. I've created a gui and world plugin. Both are running at the same time and model creation with sdf::ElementPtr is looking good so far. But communication between the gui and world plugin is a bit complex (qt signal&slots needed